# Placing buttons on FSCalendar UIView

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I'm trying to achieve this calendar (image attached), by using FSCalendar, [image]

All works fine except, any button I add inside FSCalendar UIView is 
un-clickable in simulator, I do have gesture recognizers in the calendar view to shift between months and weeks, so apparently the reason for my problem is that,

How can I add those buttons to the calendar without disabling the calendar pan gesture recognizers? and how can the headerview be aligned to the left of the calendar instead of center?

Comment: I don't think FSCalendar supports such customisations. You'll likely have to write your own calendar view.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I add those buttons to the calendar without disabling the calendar pan gesture recognizers?

I suggest you to add the button in calendar's superView. You will get the same UI looking.

```
superView.addSubview(calendar)
superView.addSubview(btn)
```

---

> how can the headerview be aligned to the left of the calendar instead of center?

Then you should change the source code. Because the `FSCalendarHeaderView.h` did not fits.

`FSCalendarHeaderView` has a collectionView `FSCalendarCollectionView`, which is the headerview you need . The `FSCalendarCollectionView`'s layout `FSCalendarHeaderLayout` does not fit.

You should change its size. Then call `FSCalendarHeaderView`'s method `- (void)setScrollOffset:(CGFloat)scrollOffset;` to make it aligned to the left of the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

First let me know which tool you use to make User interface,
if you you use Visual Studio, then go to right side of page and select Tool box and write drop down menu and then select drop down menu and use..

Comment: visual studio 2017 in c# .net

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the buttons are in front of the calendar,

```
    view.bringSubviewToFront(myButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another view at the top of the fscalendar view.

Comment: Tried that. no result.